# Late selected answer is repless

Tags: support, reputation, answers

I'm assuming that if you don't select an answer for a question that you have asked within a certain time-span, that you will get no bounty. I asked the question shown in the image a couple months back.

[image: me]

Correct me if I'm wrong. And if I'm wrong, I'd like to see it implemented, because I think it's a good idea :)

Comment: @CarlVeazey I don't think "everything you could possibly want to know about reputation" is a good duplicate target for this question, although it's certainly a good overall reference.

Comment: erm... where on "How does Reputation work?" Sorry if I missed it.

Comment: Ohhh... Duh. Nevermind. Thanks.

Comment: @BlueIce 4th bullet point under "you gain reputation when"

Comment: Yup. <sigh> well that's the stupid question for today.

Comment: @AnnaLear I apoligize

Comment: @CarlVeazey No worries. I get the motivation behind linking folks to the canonical posts like that. :)

Comment: @BlueIce Happens to the best of us. I don't mind deleting this question if you'd rather not keep it around. Let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no [bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on that question.

You accepted your own answer. We don't award you either the +15 reputation for having an accepted answer or the +2 reputation for accepting an answer in that case for obvious reasons.